# choice as in int

Tags: java

So far I have written choice as a string but I need to write it to accept int instead of string. The user has to enter 1, 2, 3 and if they enter 1 or 2 the program should continue but if the user enters 3 the program ends.

normally I write the choice as

```
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
```

Is there a way to write the code similar to that? I found a way using if statements but that screws up the rest of my code so I'm trying to find a way around that.

Thanks,

Comment: don't you know how to convert a string into integer? or didn't you google it?

Comment: @deporter indeed this seems a question that you find 10 times faster with google then doing all the trouble of asking it on stackverflow. But hey, who am I to question it :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be better to to this with a so called switch construct

```
int choice = readInt();
switch(choice){
    case 1:
    case 2:
        // your code
        break;
    case 3:
        // exit code
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
final int STOP_CHOICE = 3;
String choice = "1";

while (Integer.parseInt(choice) != STOP_CHOICE)
    {
```

Note that a non-integer choice will cause [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) to throw a [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html), so you may want to do it somewhere else and `catch` that possibility.